# Sprite custom class not working properly, why?

Tags: java, logic, sprite

As you will see in the code, I've tried to make a custom sprite class, but for some reason, the values of the variables "disappear" , and if (as you will see) `isSprite` is true, then even the mainframe won't appear/won't be visible, and it will just run in the background until you stop it manually.

Here is the code of the class:

```
package testowhat;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Sprite extends Component {

Sprite(String image1) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
 playerConstructor(image1); 

}

Integer imgPosX;        Integer imgPosY;
Integer divideSize2;    Integer divideSize1;
Integer Height;         Integer Width;
Integer numberOfSpriteCells, numberOfSpriteLayers, numberOfCellsInALine, heightOfCells, widthOfCells, countingNumber1, countingNumber2;
BufferedImage picture;
Boolean isSprite;
String image;
JPanel picturePanel = new JPanel() {    
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(picture.getScaledInstance(picture.getWidth()/divideSize1, picture.getHeight()/divideSize2, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), imgPosX, imgPosY, null);
        }     
};

private void playerConstructor(String image) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
        picture = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
    } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println("File is missing.");}
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Height = picture.getHeight()+10;
    Width = picture.getWidth()+10;
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
     picturePanel.setLocation(this.getLocation());
     picturePanel.setSize(this.getHeight(), this.getWidth());
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    picturePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Height, Width));
    picturePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Height, Width));
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (this.isVisible() == true) {
      picturePanel.setVisible(true);  
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    this.countingNumber1 = 0;
    checkThem();
    justDoIt();

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void checkThem() {
    if (isSprite == null) {
        isSprite = false;
    }
    if (imgPosX == null) {
      imgPosX = 0;
      imgPosY = 0;
    }
    if (imgPosY == null) {
      imgPosX = 0;
      imgPosY = 0;
    }
    if (numberOfSpriteCells == null) {
        numberOfSpriteCells = 6;
    }
    if (widthOfCells == null) {
        widthOfCells = 103;
    }
    if (heightOfCells == null) {
        heightOfCells = 89;
    }
    if (numberOfSpriteLayers == null) {
        numberOfSpriteLayers = 2;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void justDoIt() throws InterruptedException {
    if (isSprite == true) {
    for (countingNumber2=1; countingNumber2<7; countingNumber2++) {
      doChange();
      Thread.sleep(100);
      this.repaint();
      this.picturePanel.repaint();
      if (countingNumber2 <= 7) {
          countingNumber2 = 1;
      }
    } 
 }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void doChange() {
    imgPosX = imgPosX - widthOfCells;
    countingNumber1 = countingNumber1++;
    repaint();
    picturePanel.repaint();
    if (countingNumber1==numberOfSpriteCells/numberOfSpriteLayers) {
        imgPosY = imgPosY - heightOfCells;
        imgPosX = 0;
    }
    if (countingNumber1 == numberOfSpriteCells) {
        countingNumber1 = 0;
        imgPosX = 0;
        imgPosY = 0;
        repaint();
        picturePanel.repaint();
    }
   }
}
```

As a sidenote:

> I. In the first "version" of the code the `doChange()` procedure was in
>   another class.
>
> II. The `setbounds` of the picture, and the `picturepanel` are declared in
>   another class, but is connected.
>
> III. For some reason most of the set variables seem to lose their
>   values
>
> IV. I've already had a `nullPointerException` problem with inserting the
>   `doChange()` procedure, so I'm guessing that maybe that's the one which
>   causes these problems.

The results of running the program:

If the `isSprite` is set to false then:[image]

It runs smoothly and displays the part of the picture we (I) wanted.

and if it is set to true:[image]

Nothing happens, it runs, but nothing will appear, it is just not working correctly.

Comment: Only debugging can help

Comment: I'm really new to programming, what do you recommend how should i do it?

Comment: Again, debug the values.

Comment: ...with the debugger that comes with netbeans

Comment: Oh, okay, Thank you!